# add_action before theme setup

Tags: actions

I have a class which loads the image sliders on some add_action.
There is a function/method "render_slider" which renders the sliders  on the page based on the slider selected.
The theme tries to get the image slider object  before the sliders are loaded.

I tried with init,plugins_loaded,to load the slider.

But still  I get the error object not found

```
class Sliders {
  public function __construct() {
    add_filter( 'add_sliders', array( $this, 'add_sliders' ) );
    add_filter('plugins_loaded',array($this,'load_sliders'),10);
  }
  public function add_sliders($sliders) {
  }
  public function  load_sliders() {  
     $sliders_to_load = apply_filters( 'add_sliders', array() );
     foreach ( $sliders_to_load as $slider )
        $this->sliders[ $slider->id ] = $slider;
  }
  public function render_slider($slider_type = ''){  
      switch($slider_type){
          case 'rotator' : $rotator = $this->sliders[$slider_type];break; //Object Not Found
          default: break;
      }
  }
}
```

Comment: when you construct the class? i.e. when you call `new Sliders`?

Comment: Instance is created by the action init

Comment: That's your problem. 'plugins_loaded' is triggered **before** than 'init'. So when you create an the Slider instance and add hook to 'plugins_loaded' it does nothing: you can't add a function to an hook that have been already fired... use 'plugins_loaded' to create the instance, and inside __construct use `add_filter('after_setup_theme',array($this,'load_sliders'),10);`

Comment: I created instanse on action plugins_loaded and then I load the sliders on action after_theme_setup. Till here it works fine. It loads the slider. Then again I get the object not found. I checked the code it loads the slider only once. Dont know where I am missing?

Comment: You should load the slides once, and then use all the times you need. You don't say how are you using the slider (from a shortcode? from template tag?) nor what the `add_slider` method actually does...

Answer (score 1):

`setup_theme` run on init theme, before `after_setup_theme`.

The follow order on frontend, was fired in my test:

1. load_textdomain
2. plugins_loaded
3. auth_cookie_valid
4. set_current_user
5. sanitize_comment_cookies
6. setup_theme
7. after_setup_theme
8. init

Comment: Thanks  in listing the actions trigger list in sequence. I instance the slider using plugins_loaded and the load the slider using after_setup_theme. but still the object is not found. while rendering the slider. (Sliders are loaded after_setup_theme and again intialized to empty).

Comment: If you want to be sure, than trigger the same hook with different priority, like slider via priority 10 on `after_setup_theme` and render slider via priority 11 on `after_setup_theme`.

Comment: when the admin_enqueue_scripts action is triggerd?

Comment: Is after_setup_theme is triggerd in ajax call?

Comment: Maybe, but the right hook is [`wp_ajax_*`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_ajax_(action))

Answer (score 0):

Ok. I found an other way by saving the permalink path to the wp_options. And checking whether the current page's url path is in the options list.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).